# Entity framework 4.0 and 5.0 Code First hint IQueryable query with NOLOCK

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5.0 Code First.We are unable to implement nolock on each read query. Please find below code.

My Model :

```
public class UserType
{
    public UserType()
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        DeletedFlag = false;
    }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    public string UserTypeName { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool DeletedFlag { get; set; }
}
```

RepositoryBase:( we are using repository design pattern)

```
 public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class
    {
            return DataContext.Set<T>();
    }
```

Service:

```
//TODO: place NOLOCK
repBase.Query<UserType>().Where(ja => ja.DeletedFlag == false).OrderByDescending(ja => ja.UpdatedDate).ToList();
```

repBase is the instance of the DB Context to call above Query().

Now we want to run above query with (NOLOCK).

Visual Studio 2012,
  EF 5.0  Code First,
  C#.Net 4.0,
  MVC Web API,
  Repository Design Pattern

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just can't emit a no-lock hint (or any hint) with EF. But, just curious, what do you need it for?

Comment: To avoid deadlocks and allow dirty reads, internal app modifies the data, but public facing site is just readonly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported. EF never emits `NOLOCK` in the queries and there is no way to do that except executing direct SQL through `Database.SqlQuery` or `DbSet.SqlQuery`. If you want to have `NOLOCK` generated by EF you can download EF source code and modify its SQL generation engine to add the hint. Anyway you should think twice about using `NOLOCK` globally.

Comment: To avoid deadlocks and allow dirty reads, internal app modifies the data, but public facing site is just readonly.